# Reading from large text files in c# causing memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I am trying to read from a large text file with a word on each line and put all the values into an SQL database, with a small text file this works fine but when I have a larger text file, say 300,000 lines I run out of memory.

What is the best way to avoid this? Is there a way to read only a portion of the file, add this to the database then take it out of memory and move on to the next portion?

Here is my code so far:

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/content/wordlist.txt");
    StreamReader word_stream = new StreamReader(path);
    string wordlist = word_stream.ReadToEnd();
    string[] all_words = wordlist.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I then loop through the array adding each value to the database, but when the file is to large it simply doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
// Choose the size of the buffer according
// to your requirements and/or available memory.

int bufferSize = 256 * 1024 * 1024;

string path = Server.MapPath("~/content/wordlist.txt");

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream, bufferSize))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        ... put line into DB ...
    }
}
```

Also, do not forget exception handling.

Comment: with this method it works with a small text file but with the large file I have left the page loading for 10 minutes with no results

Comment: Use a BufferedStream. I updated my answer accordingly. This would hopefully be fast enough.

Comment: seemed to speed up the process slightly, but it still took around 3 hours to process all the data and insert into the database.

Comment: @Wazzaday: You seem to have another problem. It is not .NET's file I/O routines. Reading a 120MB file with 400.000 lines (each line 300 characters) from a USB2.0 HDD (slow!), takes about **one second** only with the code from my answer. 3 hours means your time eater is rather the DB insert, if not something entirely different else.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, ill look into that part of my code :)

Comment: Just a minor correction: Accidentally, i made the test on the USB3.0 drive. There it was 1 second. On the USB2.0 drive, it took 3..4 seconds -- bit it still is a far fetch from the 3 hours you experience (sorry for the mishap)

Answer (score 1):

try it with yield return

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path);
while( !r.EndOfStream ) 
{
    string line = r.ReadLine();
    yield return line;
}
```

maybe you read ten lines yield return them, write them to the database and then the next portion.

Comment: how would I call this after every 10 lines as an example?

Comment: While `yield` is a nifty thing, exception handling might become a nightmare if you use it for scenarios where **IDisposable**'s are involved - but that really depends on the quality/structure of your source code.